# Laravel 5.1.26:NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new baby in laravel framework.I got an issue an routing.
Here is my code

```
<h2>About page</h2>
@foreach($name as $key=>$name)
<p><a href="/songs/{{$key}}">{{$name}}</a></p>
@endforeach
```

When click on each link it opens a new page to show the songs  details,but i will get this  `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` exception.

Here  is my routes.php

```
Route::get('songs/{$id}','HomeController@show');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

public function show($id)
    {
         //Songs details
        echo $id;
    }

}
```

Comment: URL params don't need {$id} - it should just be {id}

Comment: @markdwhite its worked:)

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes like,

```
Route::get('songs/{id}','HomeController@show');
```

No need of `$id`